# Fix touch not working on UILabel inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitouch

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    if (tableView == sessionListTable){
        selectedSessionId = [[self.sessionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"session_id"];
        selectedSessionName = [[self.sessionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"session_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",selectedSessionId);
        [StudentCommon sharedInstance].mTeacherSessionId = selectedSessionId;
        [self remoteSessionButtonClick];
        currentIndexPath = indexPath;
        previousIndexPath = currentIndexPath;
        [sessionListTable reloadData];
        [sessionListPopUp removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

`The`UILabel` inside table view is not responding to touch, though the touch is working only in Empty space of the cell.

Verified all the connections, constraints and classes.

Comment: by default `UILabel` user interaction is not enabled. please check it. if not enabled then enable and check.

Comment: That's not possible. If you are calling didSelectRow of UITableViewDelegate, tap on label should work fine. Show us the code.

Comment: @Nitish Hi, it was happening literally with my project, the UILabel was not responding to touch. Only the blank area inside the cell was responding to touch events. Later found that inside Attribute Inspector, some custom properties were set under User Defined Runtime Attributes which was causing this issue.

Comment: Please provide the code how do you handle user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

- Check all the properties of inside UI elements in **Attribute Inspector**,
- make sure for all of them are user interaction is “Ticked”   ☑️
- Check the properties inside **User Defined Runtime Attributes** and remove which are 
  not required.
- Check the Class name whether it’s the correct “Super Class” / “Relevant Custom  Class” or not.
- Check inside **Connections Inspector** whether the connection is having any warning ⚠️, if warning exists remove connection and connect again.

[This is the image showing the User Defined Runtime Attributes, which was causing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATOJS.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that UILabel doesn't respond to TouchUpInside event. 
Apart from that, the events those are raised in UITableViewCell, is not catchable in superview (i.e UITableViewController or UIViewController that is hosting respective table).

In order to achieve your goal, you need to change your UILabel to a UIButton. And in order to escalate TouchUpInside event to super view, you have two options:
1- Create a delegate for your cell, and utilise it in your superview.
2- Post a notification from your cell, and observe (catch) it in super view.

Good Luck. :-)